# webpack complains module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I just added an external package nameed `@company\core` to my react app. that external package has a dependency on `aws-sdk`

`@company\core` is written in typescript and built/transpiled into js.

After npm i the folder structure looks like this

```
\react-app\node_modules\aws-sdk
\react-app\node_modules\@company\core\node_modules\aws-sdk
```

But it failed at

```
import * as Core  from '@company/core';
```

The error reads:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'
    at webpackEmptyContext (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:11)
    at :3000/static/js/17.chunk.js:44252
    at :3000/static/js/17.chunk.js:44231
    at Object.<anonymous> (:3000/static/js/17.chunk.js:44239)
    at Object../node_modules/@company/core/lib/index.js (:3000/static/js/17.chunk.js:44438)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:787)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:150)
    at Module../src/utilities/amplifyInit.js (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:3118)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:787)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:150)
    at Module../src/App.js (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:121)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:787)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:150)
    at Module../src/index.js (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2470)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:787)
    at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:150)
    at Object.0 (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:3284)
    at __webpack_require__ (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:787)
    at checkDeferredModules (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33)
    at :3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1
```

Why aws-sdk is invisible? Any idea?

Comment: Does @company/core have the aws-sdk registered in the package.json? Is it in depedencies or devDependencies?

Comment: `aws-sdk` is in the package.json as dependency for `@company/core`